# Loop to last row while adding rows

Tags: excel, vba, macos

My loop is breaking a few thousand lines before the last row.

Let's say last row is up to 12000, its looping until 9800.

```
For i = 2 To lastrow
    If ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = "4" Then
        Rows(i).Insert
        Range("E" & i).Value = ws.Cells(i + 1, 5)
        i = i + 1
        lastrow = lastrow + 1
    End If  
Next i
```

Comment: what is the data type of `lastrow` ? How many rows are available in your sheet ?

Comment: and what do you mean by "breaking" is it an error, just stopping, putting in random text...

Comment: @sous2817 it's not giving me any error, just stopping. I have 11000 rows then i am adding more rows by inserting thats why i am using i = i + 1, so my lastrow adding up to 12000. So it is stopping at 9800. Can't figure out why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nathan_Sav makes a good point. I'm not sure how the `i = i + 1` and `Next i` interact with each other. I'd try it this way:

```
i = 2
While i <= lastrow
    If ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = "4" Then
        Rows(i).Insert
        Range("E" & i).Value = ws.Cells(i + 1, 5)
        i = i + 1
        lastrow = lastrow + 1
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

Without data to test this against, or the rest of the code, it's hard to be sure this will work ... so let me know how you get on.

Comment: i = i + 1 which is for inserting row, i have to insert row to next one other wise it will keep on repeating.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. Does my version error in the same way?

Comment: @ steve lovell no error, it worked perfect... awesome... can you please tell me how did you know you have to do this way, what's the difference between while and for... thank you so much

Comment: @ steve Lovell -- one more question why did you add another i = i + 1 after end if

Comment: It was mostly a guess, I wondered if the `Next i` might not increment when you'd already added 1 since it was just ensuring each iteration of the loop finished with `i` one higher than it started.

Comment: One increment for adding a row, one for moving to the next row regardless of whether a row is added.