# How can I use Lbound and Ubound using while loop in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have to use while loop cause if i am using for loop, some how my loop is not ending util the last row. But what i am confuse here i am trying to loop it fastest possible, so i am using variant range and dumping all the data in one variable. Problem is i am getting an error with this line below. Any idea how to fix it. Error is for using To is not complete.

```
          Dim allData as Variant
          allData = ws.Range("A2:Z1048576").Value

          While i = UBound(allData, 2) To LBound(allData, 2)
```

Comment: You should be using `For` and not `While` with that syntax, but note that you are looping through the columns, not the rows.

Comment: following Rory, if you want to loop through the rows, use `For i = UBound(allData) To LBound(allData)`, it will take the first dimension, which is the row

Comment: you should loop from lbound to ubound or from ubound to lbound step -1

Comment: Use a `For` loop when iterating arrays for optimal performance.

Comment: If i use For loop then i face this issue which i asked about it earlier and someone gave me that solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43765057/loop-is-not-working-till-the-last-row-in-vba/43765293?noredirect=1#comment74572247_43765293

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to iterate through each value in allData you will need nested loops, one to iterate through rows and one to iterate through columns.

Something like this should work.

```
Sub iterate2D()
    Dim allData As Variant
    allData = Range("A2:Z1048576").Value
    For i = LBound(allData) To UBound(allData)  'For Row
        For j = LBound(allData, 2) To UBound(allData, 2) 'For Column
            'Your code
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Another way to do it would be that you can simply loop through each of the cell in the selection without dumping the value of selected range in an array.

```
Sub iterate()
    For Each cell In Range("A2:Z1048576")
        'Your code
    Next
End Sub
```